# canvas to data url return null

Tags: canvas, todataurl

Can anyone explain to me why this function returns null for the variable dataURL_

```
function createsecondimage(dataURL,tempW,tempH,max_width,max_height,canvas){
var copy = document.createElement('canvas');
copy.width = max_width;
copy.height = max_height;
var copyctx = copy.getContext("2d");
var sx = (tempW - max_width) / 2
var sy = (tempH - max_height) /2
copyctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
copyctx.fillRect(0,0,max_width,max_height); 
var imgcopy = new Image();
imgcopy.src = dataURL;
imgcopy.onload = function() {
copyctx.drawImage(imgcopy, sx, sy, 800, 800,0, 0, 800, 800);
var dataURL_ = copy.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    }
 }
```

Comment: Well, this function doesn't return anything.  Did you intend return(dataURL)?  Otherwise, are you getting any console errors? (1)  I see the function is missing a closing brace. (2) Are sx,sy valid? (3) Is the image at least 800x800--or else your drawImage will fail. (4) Are you failing with security errors (CORS compliance)?

Comment: @markE Everything is passed correctly and I'm able to prepend copy to a div and see the resized image. For some reason dataURL_ is null when I check the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me when I make sure the image is CORS compliant and when I console.log(dataURL_) inside the imgcopy callback.

Remember that imgcopy.src will start an asynchronous operation so dataURL_ will not be populated immediately, but will rather be guaranteed to be loaded inside the imgcopy.onload callback.

Also, dataURL_ is only visible inside imgcopy.onload since you did `var dataURL_` inside the imgcopy.onload function.  (You're not trying to access dataURL_ outside onload are you?)

Anyway...here's your code working fine for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";
    function start(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        createsecondimage(canvas.toDataURL(),300,300,300,300,canvas);
    }


    function createsecondimage(dataURL,tempW,tempH,max_width,max_height,canvas){
        var copy = document.createElement('canvas');
        copy.width = max_width;
        copy.height = max_height;
        var copyctx = copy.getContext("2d");
        var sx = (tempW - max_width) / 2
        var sy = (tempH - max_height) /2
        copyctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
        copyctx.fillRect(0,0,max_width,max_height); 
        var imgcopy = new Image();
        imgcopy.src = dataURL;
        imgcopy.onload = function() {
            copyctx.drawImage(imgcopy, sx, sy, 300, 300,0, 0, 300, 300);
            var dataURL_ = copy.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            console.log(dataURL_);
        }
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```